# Having Latency problem with AWS ELB backed Nginx, Is there any way to add gzip, cache, SSL configurations in ELB? is gzip support on ELB?

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-elb, nginx-config, http-redirect

I added SSL to my ELB by using the AWS Certificate Manager and running Nginx on ELB backed EC2 instance.
Configured SSL in Nginx conf file

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {

       worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
  #if user hits http, then he will be redirected https
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  sendfile on;

  default_type application/octet-stream;


  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;


  root /usr/share/nginx/html;


  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

}
}
```

am facing some latency issues, So How can I add gzip, cache, some SSL configurations in ELB?

Comment: What kind of ELB do you use? In case of Application Load Balancer you need to set http-https redirection on balancer side.

Comment: Yeah @VladChikov, I did that